# Como busco una etiqueta imprimiendo su contenido ruby

Tags: ruby

Necesito hacer un codigoque me lea paginas web, y que de paso recolecte la los enlaces de re direccionamiento y copie lo que tienen adentro, es en ruby

```
  require 'net/http'
  pagina = Net::HTTP.get(ARGV[0],ARGV[1])
  puts "...Leyendo la pagina....\n#{pagina}\n=========\n"

  ahref = "<a href"
  cierra ="</a>"
  startahref = pagina.gsub(ahref)
  cierraahref = pagina.gsub(cierra)
  img = "<img"
  cierra2 = ">"
  startimg =pagina.gsub(img)
  cierraimg = pagina.gsub(cierra2)

  puts startahref

  puts "<a href...</a> cantidad : "
  ahref2 = startahref..cierraahref
  puts pagina[ahref2]

  puts "<img ...> cantidad :"
  img2 = startimg..cierraimg
  puts pagina[img2]
```

Comment: No queda claro cuál es el problema. El código que publicaste, ¿presenta alguna falla, el resultado no es el esperado? Aclara en qué parte de tu código tienes el problema, los registros o resultados de tu depuración de código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para analizar código *html/xml* y similar **no** recomendaría hacerlo a mano (a menos que sea para efectos educativos); en su lugar deberías utilizar alguna librería específica para esa tarea, por ejemplo la gema [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/).

Por ejemplo, para obtener los enlaces utilizando Nokogiri podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'net/http'

pagina  = Net::HTTP.get(ARGV[0],ARGV[1])
enlaces = Nokogiri::HTML(pagina).xpath('//a[@href]').map { |link| link['href'] }

puts enlaces
```

Esto te daría un arreglo con los enlaces (i.e. los valores de `href` de cada etiqueta `a`), no el contenido de la etiqueta como tal.

Comment: y como seria para las etiquetas de imagenes_

Comment: @FelipeOlayaOspina Sigue la misma nomenclatura `//etiqueta[@atributo]`; para la ruta de una imagen sería `'//img[@src]'`.

Comment: @FelipeOlayaOspina Si lo anterior no te funciona intenta con `'//img/src'`.

Comment: img = Nokogiri::HTML(pagina).xpath('//img/scr').map { |img| img[@scr] }

Comment: imagenes = Nokogiri::HTML(pagina).xpath('/img[@src]').map { |link| link['src'] }